# Axis and values issue in power bi

Tags: excel, charts, powerbi, forecasting

In power bi, when I add line chart I have X axis and Y axis instead of axis and values, How to fix it ?
Is there are both the same or there is a difference between them ?
[Here is the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkBy2.png)[How I turn it to this ?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VjoQI.png)

I tried googling about this problem but I didn't fine any solution .
I would appreciate any help, Thanks .

Comment: Have you tried dragging a measure or item into the Y Axis, it will plot something

Comment: It's the same, but you can even choose between primary and secondary y-axis.

Answer (score 0):

In the newer version, they are called the X-axis and Y-axis instead of the Axis and Value
This came around Jul-2022 when the New format pane become the default